# How to Derive the Proximal Operator of the Euclidean Norm?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I'm trying to derive the proximal operator of the $L_2$ norm for myself. Here is my effort: let

$$g(x)=\gamma ||x||_2.$$

The prox-operator of $g$ at the point $x$ is defined as follows:
$$\text{prox}_g(x)={\arg\,\min}_u \, g(u) + \frac{1}{2} \|u-x\|_2^2 .$$

In order to minimize it, we can take the derivatives of it :

$$0 \in \gamma  \partial||u||_2 + u-x$$

then I can rewrite the above equation as follows:
$u \in x- \gamma \partial |||u||_2$.
From there, I do not know how to further simplify it.
I was wondering whether can someone help me to understand it better ?
I know that, people have simplified it and derived a closed formula solution for it, but I'm not sure how they did it.

Comment: Related to - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681658.

Answer (score 2):

- Use the *Moreau decomposition*: $\forall \lambda > 0$,
  $$ \text{prox}_{\lambda g}(x) \equiv x - \lambda\text{prox}_{g^*/\lambda}(x/\lambda),$$

and note that

- $g^*$ (the *convex conjugate* of $g$) is the indicator function of the $\ell_2$ unit-ball (because the $\ell_2$ norm is self-dual), i.e
  $$g^*(x) \equiv i_{\|x\|_2 \le \gamma} = \begin{cases}0, &\mbox{ if } \|x\|_2 \le \gamma,\\+\infty, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
- Finally, note that if $C$ is a closed convex set, then $\text{prox}_{i_C}(x) \equiv \text{proj}_C(x)$.

Pull the pieces together and derive the answer to your question.

Comment: Could you please add more details such that it can be more helpful ?

Comment: Tell me exactly where you're stuck in the above roadmap,  and I'll provide more input.

Comment: See also - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264263.

Answer (score 0):

In summary:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda \left\| \cdot \right\|_{2}} \left( v \right) = v - \operatorname{Proj}_{ \mathcal{B}_{ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{2} } } \left( \frac{v}{\lambda} \right) = \begin{cases}
v - \lambda \frac{ \frac{v}{\lambda} }{ \left\| \frac{v}{\lambda} \right\|_{2} } & \text{ if } \left\| \frac{v}{\lambda} \right\|_{2} > 1 \\ 
v - \lambda \frac{v}{\lambda} & \text{ if } \left\| \frac{v}{\lambda} \right\|_{2} \leq 1 
\end{cases} = \left(1 - \frac{\lambda}{ \left\| v \right\|_{2} } \right)_{+} v $$

Where $ \left( x \right)_{+} = \max \left\{ 0, x \right\} $.

See [Proximal Operator of the Euclidean Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190885).