# Proximal Operator of the Euclidean Norm ($ {L}_{2} $ Norm) without Using Moreau Decomposition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, proximal-operators

I'm trying to solve the following proximal operator function (without using moreau decomposition, or conjugates, just straight up differentials):

$prox_{\lambda||\cdot||} = min_x \lambda||x||_2 + ||x-y||^2$

Took gradient, assuming the point y is not 0. (if it was, nondifferentiable)

Then, I got the following result:

$\frac{\lambda x}{||x||_2} + x - y = 0$

Trying to solve for x, it appears it's inseparable, so we can't solve for a single axis at once like the $L_1$ norm.

I then tried the following:
$\frac{\lambda x_i}{||x||_2} = y_i-x_i \forall i$.

Squaring both sides so that the denominator looks nice:

$\frac{\lambda^2 x_i^2}{||x||^2_2} = (y_i-x_i)^2 \forall i$

Now we have:

$\frac{\lambda^2x_i^2}{y_i-x_i^2} = \sum_j x_j^2 \forall j$.

However, although we have n of these equations and n unknowns, the fact that it's not a set of linear equations makes me think that it's not possible to solve this any further. However, **there is a solution for this in closed form without using the conjugate**.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you have written in the beginning is a bit confusing... do you need to calculate the proximal of the norm, that is $\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda \|{}\cdot{}\|}(v)$? Then you need to solve the problem "Min.${}_x \|x\|+\tfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-v\|^2$". Take the optimality conditions for this problem and you'll get to the solution. By the way, the answer is: $\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda \|{}\cdot{}\|}(v)=v-\lambda \Pi_{\mathcal{B}}(v/\lambda)$. Why don't you want to use the Moreau decomposition?

Comment: Just because in my class, we haven't really gotten to that point yet, though I am familiar with it. Also I'm curious as to see how this is actually solvable without it. I also edited the notation - sorry, was in a rush :(.

Comment: An additional comment: I think I have the answer but I will leave it open for a tad longer, in case more interesting solutions will come up.

Comment: In the definition of $\mathrm{prox}$, $\min$ should rather be $\mathrm{argmin}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}$
We need to solver the optimization problem
$$
\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda\|{}\cdot{}\|}(v) = \mathrm{argmin}_{x\in\Re^n}\|x\| + \tfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-v\|^2.
$$
For convenience and wlog, let $\lambda=1$. I assume that $x\neq 0$. The optimality condition we need to solve is
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\|x\|} = v-x.\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\end{align}
From \eqref{eq:1} we see that $x$ is parallel to $v$ (again, provided that $x\neq 0$). Indeed, $v=(1+1/\|x\|)x$. Let us assume that $x(v)$ has the parametric form $x(v) = \sigma(v)\cdot v$, where $\sigma:\Re^n\to\Re$. Substituting into \eqref{eq:1},
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma v}{|\sigma|\|v\|} = v-\sigma v,\tag{2}
\end{align}
From which we conclude that $\sigma(v) \cdot v$ may be either of the following candidates
\begin{align}
x(v) = \sigma v = \left(1 \pm \tfrac{1}{\|v\|} \right)v.\tag{3}\label{eq:3}
\end{align}
We plug in \eqref{eq:3} into \eqref{eq:1} and check whether it solves the optimality conditions (recall that there is a unique solution). We may verify that the following is indeed a solution
\begin{align}
x(v) =  \left(1 - \tfrac{1}{\|v\|} \right)v,\tag{4}\label{eq:4}
\end{align}
but provided that $1 - \tfrac{1}{\|v\|}\geq 0$, that is $\|v\|\geq 1$.

Comment: Great answer sir. I have accepted your answer. I did it in a similar but slightly different approach. I will post mine as well. It can generalize to non-circular L2 norms as well.

Comment: I think you should generalize and not assume $ \lambda = 1 $. Great answer. +1.

Answer (score 3):

This is just my approach to solve the question, but I have accepted Pantelis's answer.

Starting from the beginning:

$prox_{\lambda||\cdot||}(y) = argmin_x ||x|| + \frac{1}{2\lambda}||x-y||^2$.

Setting gradient to zero:

$\lambda\frac{x}{||x||} + (x-y) = 0$

$(\frac{\lambda}{||x||} + 1)x = y$

Take the norm of both sides:

$(\frac{\lambda}{||x||} + 1)||x|| = ||y||$

Treat $||x||$ as z:

$\lambda + z = ||y||$. $z = ||y|| - \lambda$.

We now know $||x|| = ||y|| - \lambda$, so plug back into the equation:

$(\frac{\lambda}{||y|| - \lambda} + 1)x = y$ and solve for the equation accordingly. It should give the same answer as what Pantelis said.

Comment: Is it differentiable for example $|x|$ is not at $0$