# Does taking Norm on both side of an equation preserve equality?

Tags: normed-spaces

I was reading the second answer from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2266037/908685

> $(\frac{\lambda}{||x||} + 1)x = y$
> Take the norm of both sides:
> $(\frac{\lambda}{||x||} + 1)||x|| = ||y||$

I am new to computing norms or the concept of vector-norms altogether. Is it always true that taking the norm on both sides of an equation will preserve equality? And why is that? I know that this is a simple question, but I hope to get some insights here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. More generally, if $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$ for any well-defined function $f$.

Comment: Note that this is a property of equality (a case of the substitution property of equality), not something special about norms.