# Proximal Operator of the Euclidean / L2 Norm

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I am trying to find the proximal point of the function $ f \left( x \right) = {\left\| x \right\|}_{2} $ where $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $

The Proximal Operator is defined as:

$$ \operatorname{prox}_{\alpha f} \left( y \right) = \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{2} $$

I have tried doing this by finding the gradient for the entire function and also by differentiating along each coordinate but neither seems to work.

Comment: By $| x |_{2}$, do you mean the 2-norm of $x$ (usually denoted $\| x \|_{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding proximal mapping is 
$$x\mapsto \Big(1-\frac{\alpha}{\max\big\{\|x\|,\alpha\big\}}\Big)x;$$
for details, see Bauschke-Combettes' *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces* (2017, second edition, Springer) Example 24.20.

Answer (score 0):

Original from my answer to - [Proximal Operator of the Euclidean Norm ($ {L}_{2} $ Norm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190885).

Given $ f \left( x \right) = \left\| x \right\| $ is a norm function its Prox is given by (For any Norm):

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda f \left( \cdot \right)} \left( v \right) = v - \lambda \operatorname{Proj}_{ \mathcal{B}_{ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{\ast} } } \left( \frac{v}{\lambda} \right) $$

Where $ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \mathcal{B}_{ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{\ast} } } \left( \cdot \right) $ is the Orthogonal Projection Operator and $ \mathcal{B}_{ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{\ast} } $ is the Norm Unit Ball (Of the Dual Norm).

In your case we're dealing with the $ {L}_{2} $ Norm which is self dual.
Moreover, the Projection onto the $ {L}_{2} $ Unit Ball is given by:

$$ \operatorname{Proj}_{ \mathcal{B}_{ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{2} } } \left( x \right) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{ \left\| x \right\|_{2} } & \text{ if } \left\| x \right\|_{2} > 1 \\ 
x & \text{ if } \left\| x \right\|_{2} \leq 1 
\end{cases} $$

In summary:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda \left\| \cdot \right\|_{2}} \left( v \right) = v - \lambda \operatorname{Proj}_{ \mathcal{B}_{ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{2} } } \left( \frac{v}{\lambda} \right) = \begin{cases}
v - \lambda \frac{ \frac{v}{\lambda} }{ \left\| \frac{v}{\lambda} \right\|_{2} } & \text{ if } \left\| \frac{v}{\lambda} \right\|_{2} > 1 \\ 
v - \lambda \frac{v}{\lambda} & \text{ if } \left\| \frac{v}{\lambda} \right\|_{2} \leq 1 
\end{cases} = \left(1 - \frac{\lambda}{ \left\| v \right\|_{2} } \right)_{+} v $$

Where $ \left( x \right)_{+} = \max \left\{ 0, x \right\} $.