# What is the shrinkage formula in image denoising?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, image-processing

The minimizing for $ \omega$ is equivalent to solving,for i=1,2,...,$n^2$,
$$\min_{w_i}=\|w_i\|_2+\frac{\beta}{2}\|w_i-D_iu\|_2^2 \; \; \; \;\;\;\;(1)$$
Which we first introduce two auxiliary vectors  $\omega_1,\omega_2\in \mathcal{R}^{n^2}$ to approximate $D^{(1)}u$ and $D^{(2)}u$,respectively,where we recall that $D^{(1)},D^{(2)}\in\mathcal{R}^{n^2\times n^2}$ and $u \in\mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$.We denote $\omega =(\omega_1;\omega_2) \in \mathcal{R}^{2n^2}$ and $D=(D^{(1)};D^{(2)})\in\mathcal{R}^{2n^2\times n^2}$,for i=1,2,...,$n^2$,we let $\omega_i=((\omega_1)_i;(\omega_2)_i) \in \mathcal{R}^2$,which is an approximation of $D_iu=[(D^{(1)}u)_i;(D^{(2)}u)_i]\in \mathcal{R}^2$.To keep $\omega_i$ close to $D_iu$,we apply a quadratic penalt term $\beta$ .In my opinion,to solve the (1):
$$when\; w_i\neq 0$$
$$\min_{w_i}=\sqrt{(\omega_1)_i^2+(\omega_2)_i^2}+\frac{\beta}{2}([(\omega_1)_i-(D^{(1)}u)_i)^2+((\omega_2)_i-(D^{(2)}u)_i)^2)]$$
By derivation then we can get:
$$\frac{(\omega_1)_i}{\left \|\omega_i  \right \|}+\beta((\omega_1)_i-(D^{(1)}u)_i)=0$$
$$\frac{(\omega_2)_i}{\left \|\omega_i  \right \|}+\beta((\omega_2)_i-(D^{(2)}u)_i)=0$$
So it means:
$$\frac{\omega_i}{\left \|\omega_i  \right \|}+\beta(\omega_i-D_iu)=0$$
$$\omega_i=D_iu-\frac{\omega_i}{\beta\left \|\omega_i  \right \|}$$
What let me feel confuse is the paper said the solution for the (1):for which the unique minimizer is given by the following two-demensional(2D) shrinkage fomula: 
$$\omega_i=max\left \{{\left \|D_iu  \right \|-\frac{1}{\beta}},0  \right \}\frac{D_iu}{\left \|D_iu \right \|},i=1,2,...,n^2\; \; \; \;\;\;\;(2)$$
So what is shrinkage formula doing for (1) to (2)?And why I get the different answer and where if I made mistakes?Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "how the formula worked"?

Comment: What is the shrinkage formula in this process?

Comment: Check out the first few slides of chapter 8 of Vandenberghe's 236c notes.  The shrinkage operator you are asking about in this question is also known as the "proximal operator of the $\ell_2$-norm."  http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf

Comment: I edited my question，can you look again?Thank you.

Comment: Are you sometimes writing $w_i$ when you mean $\omega_i$?  Is $w_i$ a scalar? If so what does the expression $\| w_i \|_2$ mean? Are you attempting to solve for $\omega_i$? But you have $\omega_i$ on both the left and right sides of your equation, so you have not solved for $\omega_i$. In any case, there is an error in your approach because you must handle the nondifferentiabity of the $\ell_2$-norm carefully.

Comment: Sorry about the written error,all $w_i$ mean $\omega_i$ and $\omega_i$ is a vector $\in \mathcal{R}^2$.I think in (1) there should be "argmin",but the paper used the "min".

Comment: I see. The main issue is that you can't simply set the gradient equal to $0$ because the $\ell_2$-norm is not differentiable at the origin. I think it's most clear to use the Moreau decomposition formula to evaluate this proximal operator.

Comment: The answer given here shows what I think is the best way to  evaluate this proximal operator: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167550/how-to-derive-the-proximal-operator-of-the-euclidian-norm/2168391#2168391