# Proximal Operator of Weighted $ {L}_{2} $ Norm

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

> Define the weighted $ {L}_{2} $ norm $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{2,w} = \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {w}_{i} {x}_{i}^{2} }$. Find the formula for $ \operatorname{prox}_{\lambda  
> {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{2,w} }(y)$, where $ \lambda > 0 $.

By definition we have:
$$ \operatorname{prox}_{\lambda {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{2,w}} \left( y \right) = \arg \min_{x} \left( \lambda \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {w}_{i} {x}_{i}^{2} } + \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} \right) $$

But I have no idea how to proceed from here. Any idea?

Comment: Proximal Operator of the $ {L}_{2} $ Norm - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681658.

Comment: Related to - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581340.

Comment: What's with the run of questions on proximal operators? If you have so many questions, it's probably better to seek a face-to-face (e.g., with the instructor, if this is for a course you're enrolled in).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Did you refer to me?

Comment: @Royi there were six or eight questions in close proximity on proximal operators, all with you as the last user. Sorry, I didn't look closely enough to see that they weren't all new questions you had just asked. If they were old questions that you edited, I'd suggest it's a bad idea to edit bunches of old questions, as it bumps new questions off the front page; one should limit oneself to three or four a day.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Yea, I just added the `proximal-operators` tag. I also added it to relevant questions. I will limit the tagging to few per day. By the way, I made a mistake spelling the tag. Could you please rename it to `proximal-operator`? No need to the last `s`. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi I don't know how to rename a tag someone else has created, and I don't know how to change it without bumping all those questions up to the front page again. Maybe you could flag this question for moderator attention and explain what you hope a moderator can do.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581340.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous answer contained a crucial mistake (thanks to the users in the comments for pointing it out) and became a mess of edits, so here's a new, correct one. Denote $\|x\|_{2,w}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i^2$. Define 
$$f(x) = \lambda\sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {w}_{i} {x}_{i}^{2} } + \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2}.$$
This is a convex function, being the sum of a norm and a scaled version of the $\ell_2$ squared norm. It is not differentiable everywhere, but it is continuous - so we can essentially replace the gradient by the **subgradient**, which is defined as 
$$\partial f(x) = \{v\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle v, y-x\rangle \text{ for all $y$}\}.$$
Then standard facts from convex analysis tell us that:

- $x$ is a minimizer of $f$ if and only if $0\in \partial f(x)$;
- if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, the subgradient $\partial f(x)$ is a singleton containing the gradient of $f$ at $x$;
- given continuous convex functions $f,g$, we have $\partial (f+g)(x)$ is the convex hull of the Minkowski sum of $\partial f(x)$ and $\partial g(x)$.

Now we compute the subgradient of $f(x)$. When $x\neq0$, both summands are differentiable and we obtain the condition
$$ \partial f(x) = \frac{\lambda}{\|x\|_{2,w}}Wx + (y-x).$$
where $W$ is a diagonal matrix with the $w_i$'s as entries.

The case $x=0$ is more interesting. The subgradient of the weighted $\ell_2$ norm at $0$ is by definition 
$$\{v \ | \ \langle v, y\rangle \leq \lambda \|y\|_{2,w}\text{ for all $y$}\}$$
which exactly means $\|v\|_{2,w}^*\leq \lambda$, where $\|\cdot\|_{2,w}^*$ is the dual norm to the weighted $\ell_2$ norm, which can easily be seen to be (use Cauchy-Schwarz) $\|y\|_{2,w}^* = \sqrt{y^T W^{-1}y}$. So the total subgradient at zero is
$$\partial f(0) = \{ v - y \ | \ \|v\|_{2,w}^*\leq \lambda\}$$.

Now we must see when $0\in\partial f(x)$.

- The condition $0\in\partial f(0)$ is that $\|y\|_{2,w}^* \leq \lambda$. So, when $\|y\|_{2,w}^* \leq \lambda$, $0$ is a global minimizer for $f$.
- The condition $0\in\partial f(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ is that 
  $$ y = \left(I + \frac{\lambda}{\|x\|_{2,w}}W\right) x$$
  One can see by taking the squared $\|\cdot\|_{2,w}^*$ norm of the right hand side that it is $> \lambda$ when $x\neq 0$ and all the weights $w_i$ are positive. Thus, **the two cases for a global minimizer are exclusive**. Furthermore, one can from the above equation after some manipulations solve for the minimizer $x$ explicitly.

Comment: Maybe to clarify the first term can be obtained by applying the chain rule on $f(g(x)), \cases{f(x) = \sqrt{x}\\ g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i{x_i}^2}$.

Comment: I think this is not the closed form answer as $ W $ depends on $ {x}_{i} $. For example if we set $ {w}_{i} = 1 $ for all $ i $ we should get the result of the Proximal Operator of the vanilla $ {L}_{2} $ Norm as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681658. But the results are not the same.

Comment: The function we are minimizing is not differentiable, though, so we can't simply set the gradient equal to $0$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: @littleO, I think the answer is wrong for many reasons (See my comment above). I am trying to get amakelov response but he seems to ignore. I hope he will answer as I think it is a marked answer which is wrong.

Comment: I have added some details in the answer, please check it out

Comment: @Royi pointed out that you don't get the correct answer if all the weights are equal to $1$. What do you think about that?

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you. i have posted a new answer fixing this

Comment: @amakelov, It has been a year I'm asking you to address this. Why ignoring the comments?

Comment: i'm sorry, i haven't been paying any attention to this website for a long while

Comment: It has also now been 3 years since amakelov answered this question, it had been two years when you asked your follow-up. I think *demanding* an answer years later is a bit immature. Believe it or not, some people do move on from this site.

Comment: @Andnp, you know one can see the last visit of any user to the site, right? So I could have seen the user log into the site and ignored. I think it is not good for the community that wrong answers are marked as correct ones.