# Orthogonal Projection onto the Weighted $ {L}_{2} $ Norm Ball

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

Projection onto the $\ell$2 norm ball is known. Let the norm ball set reads
$C = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \left\| x - c \right\|_2^2 \leq  d^2  \right\}$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}$, then the [projection onto this norm ball set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627034/orthogonal-projection-onto-the-l-2-unit-ball) can be shown as
\begin{align}
\Pi_{C} \left ( y \right) = c + \frac{d}{\max \left\{\left\| y - c \right\|_2, d \right\}} \left( y - c \right) \ .
\end{align}

> How to obtain a projection onto the weighted $\ell$2 norm ball, where the set $C = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \left\| x - c \right\|_W^2 \leq  d^2  \right\}$, where $W$ is a positive definite matrix?

---

Note: There is an attempt for [weighted l2 norm projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263447/proximal-operator-of-weighted-l2-norm), but we don't have the same problem definition (or may be I can't figure out yet how to massage that answer).

---

My partial attempt:

Following Brian's comments, I have made an attempt. But I am stuck and not able to compute the Lagrange multiplier.

The weighted $\ell$2 projection problem can be expressed as
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad & \left\|y-x\right\|_2^2\\
\text{subject to }\quad & \left\|x-c\right\|_W^2 \leq d^2
\end{align}

Forming the Lagrangian:
\begin{align*}
L\left(x, \lambda\right) 
&=  \left\|y-x\right\|_2^2 + \lambda \left(  \left[ (x-c)^T W (x-c) \right]- d^2 \right) .
\end{align*}

Then according to the stationarity condition of the KKT conditions, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0 \Rightarrow 
&=  -(y - x) + \lambda \left(W (x-c) \right)  = 0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow x = \left( I + \lambda W \right)^{-1} \left(\lambda W  c + y  \right).
\end{align*}

Now I am stuck and don't know how to obtain $\lambda$ in closed-form? I thought about considering the complementary slackness of the KKT conditions, but then it becomes too much involved for me. 
Say $\lambda > 0$, then
\begin{align}
(x-c)^T W (x-c) = d^2 \ . 
\end{align}
If I plugin $x = \left( I + \lambda W \right)^{-1} \left(\lambda W  c + y  \right)$ in the above equation, then I don't know how to solve for $\lambda$. If we can't find it in closed-form, then how to obtain this iteratively? How about if $W$ is a diagonal matrix, then can we obtain $\lambda$ in closed-form?

---

Further attempt: If $W$ is a diagonal matrix, then following the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263447/proximal-operator-of-weighted-l2-norm), $i$th coordinate of $x$ can be written as
\begin{align}
x_i = \frac{\lambda W_i c_i + y_i}{1 + \lambda W_i} .
\end{align}

Now, plugging into the complementary slackness condition such that
\begin{align}
(x-c)^T W (x-c) &= \|W^{1/2} (x-c)\|^2 = d^2 \\
&\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{W_i} (x_i - c_i) = \pm d \\
&\Leftrightarrow \lambda = \frac{\pm 1}{d \sqrt{W_i}} \left(y_i - c_i \right) - \frac{1}{W_i} \ . 
\end{align}
Is this correct in case of $W$ is a diagonal matrix?

Question: Would $\lambda$ be different for different coordinates of the vector? Hmm, should it not be a constant for all coordinates?

Comment: It's relatively easy to set this up as a constrained optimization problem and apply the Lagrange multiplier method.  If your $W$ matrix is diagonal, this simplifies to the case discussed in the question you linked to.  Is your $W$ diagonal?  If not, then the problem is still relatively easy to solve by iterative schemes.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I have made an attempt based on your suggestion (please see above). But I don't know how to obtain $\lambda$ in closed-form even if $W$ is a diagonal matrix. Can you help me how to solve for $\lambda$? Any reference?

Comment: Have you thought what the matrix is doing to space? Specifically to the ball?

Comment: @Royi my impression is that this matrix $W$ are giving different weights to respective coordinates. So, the norm ball may look non-spherical depending on the considered weights. Please correct me if my impression is wrong.

Comment: PSD Matrices has special shapes in space. I think it might assist you with the solution.

Comment: Ok thank you. So, do you have any solution to my question? or any exact reference that has solved such a problem? Thanks

Comment: The Lagrangian factor $ \lambda $ is a scalar as the inequality is scalar.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, Do you have closed form solution for the Diagonal Case? It seems to me one needs iterative method to find $ \lambda $ in the diagonal case as well. If you look at my solution, If you have a Closed form Solution for the Diagonal Case, you have a closed form solution for the PSD case.

Answer (score 3):

The objective function is given by:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} & \text{} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {\left( x - c \right)}^{T} W \left( x - c \right) \leq d
\end{align*}$$

#### Case I - Diagonal Matrix

In this case the matrix $ W $ is diagonal with $ {w}_{ii} \geq 0 $.

*Let's assume we know how to solve this*.

**Remark**
I could find a simple iterative method to find $ \lambda $ for this case but not a closed form solution. Though I'd guess it is doable. As we can change coordinates to make the Ellipsoid into a Ball and then go back.

#### Case II - Positive Definite Matrix

In this case the matrix $ W $ a [Positive Semi Definite (PSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) Matrix - $ W \succeq 0 $.

Since $ W $ is a PSD matrix it can be written as (Eigen Decomposition):

$$ W = {P}^{T} D P $$

Where $ P $ is [Unitary Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and $ D $ is Diagonal Matrix with $ {d}_{ii} \geq 0 $.

Then one could rewrite the problem as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} & \text{} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {\left( x - c \right)}^{T} {P}^{T} D P \left( x - c \right) \leq d
\end{align*}$$

Defining $ v = P x $, $ z = P y $ and $ e = P c $ one could rewrite the problem as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} & \text{} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {\left( v - e \right)}^{T} D \left( v - e \right) \leq d
\end{align*}$$

Now, since $ P $ is Unitary Matrix which means it preserves the $ {L}_{2} $ norm and is invertible then $ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| P \left( x - y \right) \right\|}_{2}^{2} = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| v - z \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ and the whole problem becomes:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{v} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| v - z \right\|}_{2}^{2} & \text{} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {\left( v - e \right)}^{T} D \left( v - e \right) \leq d
\end{align*}$$

Where $ D $ is Diagonal Matrix which is exactly Case I we assume we know how to solve.

#### Code

I created a MATLAB code to solve the problem (The general).
The code is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q3079400 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q3079400).

Comment: This looks good, Royi. I agree that we need to know if a closed form exists for the diagonal case. +1

Comment: As I wrote, it is easy to solve with few iterations of Binary Search. The question is if that what you want? I hope @BrianBorchers have a closed form solution for that.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581340.