# Proximal Operator of $ f \left( x \right) = {\left\| A x \right\|}_{2} $ Where $ A $ Is Diagonal Matrix (Weighted $ {L}_{2} $ Norm)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

How to compute the proximal mapping (prox-operator) of  $f(x)=||Ax||_{2}$?

Here $A$ is a diagonal matrix with all positive eigenvalues.

I know how to compute the prox mapping of $f(x)=||x||_{2}$, but I have not found any connection between these two functions. I found someplace saying that for general $A$, with $g(x)=f(Ax)$ the prox-operator of $g(x)$ does not follow easily from prox-operator of $f(x)$. See  [L. Vandenberghe - The Proximal Mapping](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf) at composition with affine mapping.

Comment: Since $ A $ is diagonal in your case it is related to - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263447.

Comment: @Royim, Hi, I've checked. But I would also like to find a close-form solution.

Comment: I think @Ze-NanLi solved it for you nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I made a mistake in my calculations, and have edited it.**

According to the Moreau decomposition, for $t > 0$
\begin{equation}
x = \operatorname{prox}_{t f}(x) + t \operatorname{prox}_{t^{-1} f^{*}}(x / t).
\end{equation}
Now we first compute the conjugate of $f(x)=\|Ax\|$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f^*(u) &= \sup_{x}~ \langle u,x \rangle - f(x) \\
&= \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
{0} & {\text{if}~\|A^{-1}u\| \leq 1,} \\
{+\infty} & {\text{otherwise.}}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
 And then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{prox}_{t^{-1}f^*}(x/t) &= \arg\min_{u} f^*(u) + \frac{t}{2}\|u-\frac{x}{t}\|^2 \\
&= \arg\min_{\|A^{-1}u\| \leq 1} \frac{t}{2}\|u-\frac{x}{t}\|^2 \\
&= \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
{\frac{x}{t}} & {\text{if}~\|A^{-1}x\| \leq t ,} \\
{\frac{A^TAx}{tA^TA + \lambda I}} & {\text{otherwise.}}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is the solution of 
\begin{equation}
\|\frac{Ax}{tA^TA+ \lambda I}\| = 1.
\end{equation}
Finally, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{prox}_{tf}(x) &= x-t \operatorname{prox}_{t^{-1}f^*}(x/t)  \\
&= \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
{0} & {\text{if}~\|A^{-1}x\| \leq t ,} \\
{(I - \frac{A^TA}{A^TA + \frac{\lambda}{t}I})x} & {\text{otherwise.}}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
(If $A=I$ and $f$ will be reduced to Euclidean norm.)

Since $A$ is a diagonal matrix with all positive eigenvalues , the Fenchel Conjugate  of $f(x)$ can be computed by the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f^*(u) &= \sup_{x} \langle u, x \rangle - \|Ax\| \\
&=\sup_{y=Ax} \langle A^{-1}u, y \rangle - \|y\| = g^*(A^{-1}u),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $g$ is Euclidean norm $g(x)=\|x\|$. Since the conjugate of $g(x)$ is
\begin{equation}
g^*(x^*)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
{0} & {\text{if}~\|x\| \leq 1,} \\
{+\infty} & {\text{otherwise.}}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Thus 
\begin{equation}
f^*(u) = g^*(A^{-1}u)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
{0} & {\text{if}~\|A^{-1}u\| \leq 1,} \\
{+\infty} & {\text{otherwise.}}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

For the computation of $\lambda$, one can refer to @River Li's answer, or solve it easily through Lagrangian multiplier method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you please show the "steps" to obtain the conjugate function $f^*(u)$? Also, the norm of a matrix $A$ is Frobenius norm, i.e., $||A||_2$?

Comment: @learning, sorry. I forget how to prove it, and maybe the original answer is incorrect. Anyway, I am very appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @Ze-NanLi, hi I think you miss the dual norm mark when derivate the conjugate function

Comment: @YuzheChen, I understand what you mean. But I did not miss the dual norm mark, because the dual norm of Euclidean norm is itself.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\mathrm{prox}_{f}(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{u\in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{\|Au\|_2
+ \tfrac{1}{2}\|u - x\|_2^2\right\}. \tag{1}$$
Let $u^\ast$ be the solution of the optimization problem in (1). 
Note that if $u\ne 0$, then $\|Au\|_2$ is differentiable, and $\nabla \|Au\|_2 = \frac{A^TAu }{\|Au\|_2}$.
Thus, if $u^\ast \ne 0$, then the gradient of the objective function at $u^\ast$ vanishes, i.e.
$$\frac{A^TAu^\ast }{\|Au^\ast \|_2} + u^\ast - x = 0$$
which results in
$$u^\ast = \Big(\frac{A^TA }{\|Au^\ast \|_2} + I_n\Big)^{-1} x. \tag{2}$$
Also, if there does not exist $u^\ast \ne 0$ satisfying (2), then $u^\ast = 0$.

Let us solve (2). Let $A = \mathrm{diag}(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$. Let $\lambda = \|Au^\ast \|_2 > 0$. From (2), we have
$$u^\ast_i = \frac{\lambda}{a_i^2 + \lambda} x_i, \ \forall i. \tag{3}$$
From (3) and $\lambda^2 = \|Au^\ast \|_2^2 > 0$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i^2x_i^2}{(a_i^2 + \lambda)^2} = 1. \tag{4}$$
Let
$$F(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i^2x_i^2}{(a_i^2 + \lambda)^2}.$$
Note that $F(\infty) = 0$ and $F(0) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{a_i^2} = \|A^{-1}x\|_2^2$.
Also, $F(\lambda)$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \infty)$.
Thus, $F(\lambda) = 1$ has a unique positive solution if and only if $F(0) > 1$ i.e. $\|A^{-1}x\|_2 > 1$.
As a result, we have
$$\mathrm{prox}_{f}(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                                  0 & \|A^{-1}x\|_2 \le 1 \\[6pt]
                                  (\frac{1}{\lambda}A^TA + I_n)^{-1} x &  \|A^{-1}x\|_2 > 1
                                \end{array}
\right. \tag{5}$$
where $\lambda$ is the unique positive solution of (4).

**Remark 1**: In general, $\lambda$ cannot be expressed in closed form (see Remark 2). 
If $A = I_n$ (or $A = \alpha I_n$), $\lambda$ can be expressed in closed form.
For example, $A = I_n$, then (4) becomes $\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{(1+\lambda)^2} = 1$ and hence $\lambda = \|x\|_2 - 1$. Thus, from (5), we have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{prox}_{\|x\|_2}(x) &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                                  0 & \|x\|_2 \le 1 \\[6pt]
                                 (1 - \frac{1}{\|x\|_2})x &  \|x\|_2 > 1
                                \end{array}
\right.\\
&= \Big(1 - \frac{1}{\max(\|x\|_2, 1)}\Big)x.
\end{align}
This is a well-known result.

**Remark 2**: Numerical results verify our result (5). We use CVX+Matlab to solve the optimization problem in (1).

Let us see an example. Let $x = [-3, 2, -1, 1]^T$ and $A = \mathrm{diag}(1, 2, 3, 4)$. Equation (4) becomes
$$\frac{9}{(\lambda+1)^2} + \frac{16}{(\lambda+4)^2} + \frac{9}{(\lambda+9)^2} + \frac{16}{(\lambda+16)^2} = 1,$$
which, after clearing the denominator, results in
\begin{align}
&\lambda^8+60\lambda^7+1396\lambda^6+15840\lambda^5+86511\lambda^4\\
& +143320\lambda^3-568624\lambda^2-2517120\lambda-3043584 = 0.
\end{align}
In general, there is no closed form solution to an equation of 8th degree.
Using Maple, we have $\lambda = 2.989390606...$.
We use CVX+Matlab to solve the optimization problem in (1), which is compared with (5).
We have
$$\mathrm{prox}_{f}([-3, 2, -1, 1]^T) \approx [-2.2480,    0.8554,   -0.2493,    0.1574]^T.$$

Comment: Nice solution, I made a mistake in my answer, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Ze-NanLi  Your solution is impressive by using Moreau decomposition and Fenchel Conjugate.