# Projection of an interior point of an ellipsoid onto itself

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp, ellipsoids

Consider

$$E := \{ x \in \Bbb R^n \mid x^T D x = 1 \}$$

an ellipsoid constructed by the diagonal matrix $D = \mbox{diag}(d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n)$ with $d_i > 0,\ \forall i \in [n]$. Suppose that $z$ is inside the ellipsoid, $z^T D z < 1$. What is the projection of $z$ on the surface of the ellipsoid $E$? Does the following nonconvex problem have a closed-form solution?
\begin{equation} 
\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}  \
\|x-z\|_2^2        \qquad \textrm{subject to} \qquad x^TDx=1.
\end{equation}

I doubt that there is a closed-form solution, following the standard procedure of KKT conditions. My inquiries on finding effective numerical methods show that there are numerical methods to solve the following related problem, for $z$ with $z^TDz>1$

\begin{equation}
\min_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\  \|x-z\|_2^2
 \qquad \mbox{subject to}  \qquad  x^TDx\le 1.
\end{equation}

See [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2017.01.008), for example. Any ideas on how I can probably use these methods? Or are there papers that discuss how to find a projection of a point inside an ellipsoid onto it?

I appreciate any useful information.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581340/proximal-operator-of-f-left-x-right-left-a-x-right-2-where

Comment: @user550103 Thank you! I will look into it!

Comment: @Sam  Did you try the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @RiverLi I actually did but nothing that I could get!

Comment: Where do you expect $x=0$ to end up if all $d_i$ are equal? Or are you only interested in the objective value?

Comment: Is $E$ an ellipsoid or an ellipsoidal surface?

Comment: The ellipsoidal surface would be better wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the $D$ matrix is diagonal makes the problem much easier. The Lagrangian is:
$$L(x,y) = ||x-z||_2^2 + y\left(x^TDx-1\right)$$
so the KKT conditions are:
$$(x_i-z_i) + yd_i x_i = 0 \quad \forall i$$
$$x^TDx = 1$$
The stationarity condition can also be expressed as:
$$x_i = \frac{z_i}{1+yd_i}.$$
This simple expression is only possible because $D$ is diagonal, which gave rise to the term $yd_ix_i$. Due to symmetry, you know $x_i^*$ has the same sign as $z_i$, so $y\geq -1/(\max_i d_i)$. Note that $y=0$ is impossible (it leads to $x^T D x = z^TDz <1$), and that $y>0$ implies $|x_i| \leq |z_i| \; \forall i$ which is also not possible, so $y<0$ All that's left is finding $y$ for which $-1/(\max_i d_i) \leq y < 0$ and
$$\sum_i d_i \left( \frac{z_i}{1+y d_i}\right)^2 = 1.$$
Since the left hand side is monotonously decreasing in $y$, you can use bisection search.

Comment: This is fantastic. I really appreciate your time and effort. Voting up now and most probably will be accepted as the solution later. Looking forward for other possible solutions till the deadline but I am not really sure how they would beat yours! Thank you so much again.

Comment: Could you please explain how symmetry results in having the same sign for $x_i$ and $z_i$? I am basically thinking about a scenario in which the problem has multiple solutions, maybe that does not happen!?

Comment: I can see that the solution is not necessarily unique, at least for $x=0$.

Comment: symmetry: you can work out all $+/-$ cases, but intuitively, if you put $-|x_i^*|$ and $|x_i^*|$ on the line of reals (both are feasible), $|x_i^*|$ is closer to positive numbers and $-|x_i^*|$ is closer to negative numbers. Since the squared distance is in the objective, $x_i^* = |x_i^*|$ has a better objective value when $z_i < 0$ (and $x_i^* = -|x_i^*|$. is better when $z_i>0$)

Comment: When $z_i=0$ for $i \in I$ with $I = \text{argmax}_i d_i$, the problem is a bit harder because $x_i=0$ is clearly not optimal (think 2d with $z=(1,0)$ and $d=(1,0.01)$). Setting $y=-1/(\max_i d_i)$ satisfies stationarity for $i\in I$, determines $x_i$ for $i \not\in I$ from the stationarity conditions, and then the other $x_i$ follow from $x^T Dx = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this problem is from a bounding perspective, although it only gives insight into the optimal distance $\|x^*-z\|_2$, and not necessarily localization information of $x^*$ itself in general.

In particular, note that we can define a lifted variable $X=xx^\top$. Then the left side of the constraint can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
x^\top Dx = \text{tr}(x^\top Dx) = \text{tr}(Dxx^\top) = \text{tr}(DX).
\end{equation*}
Similarly, the objective can be written as
\begin{equation*}
\|x-z\|_2^2 = x^\top x - 2z^\top x + z^\top z = \text{tr}(X)-2z^\top x + z^\top z.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, the projection problem is equivalent to the following:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^n,X\in\mathbb{S}^n}{\text{minimize}} && \text{tr}(X)-2z^\top x + z^\top \\
&\text{subject to} && \text{tr}(DX)=1, \\
&&& X=xx^\top.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Under this reformulation, the objective is affine, and the old equality constraint is also affine. However, the nonconvexity has been absorbed into the new constraint $X=xx^\top$. If you relax this constraint to $X\succeq xx^\top$, the problem becomes convex, since $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{S}^n$ defined by $f(x,X)=xx^\top-X$ is cone-convex with respect to the positive semidefinite cone. Indeed, using Schur complements, we can further rewrite the condition that $X-xx^\top\succeq 0$ as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x^\top \\
x & X
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{equation*}
Since we've introduced a relaxation of your original problem, we conclude that the following (convex) semidefinite programming problem lower bounds your original problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^n,X\in\mathbb{S}^n}{\text{minimize}} && \text{tr}(X)-2z^\top x + z^\top \\
&\text{subject to} && \text{tr}(DX)=1, \\
&&& \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x^\top \\
x & X
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Note that in the case the final constraint is active at optimum, i.e., $X^*=x^*x^{*\top}$, you can conclude that $x^*$ solves the original nonconvex problem.

For the other side of things, you can upper bound the optimal value by looking at the eigenvalues of $D$. In particular, the eigenvalues of $D$ are precisely the diagonal elements of $D$ (since it is a diagonal matrix per your assumption). Without loss of generality, let us assume $d_1\ge d_2\ge \cdots \ge d_n$. Then the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $d_i$ is $e_i$, the $i$th standard basis vector. Let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_i}}e_i$. Then we remark that $x$ is feasible for your original optimization problem, since
\begin{equation*}
x^\top Dx = \frac{1}{d_i}e_i^\top De_i = \frac{1}{d_i}e_i^\top (d_i e_i) = e_i^\top e_i = 1.
\end{equation*}
The corresponding objective value is
\begin{equation*}
\|x-z\|_2^2 = \left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_i}}e_i - z\right\|_2^2.
\end{equation*}
This value trivially upper bounds the optimal objective value of the minimization problem. Since this holds for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, we conclude that the following upper bounds the optimal value of the problem:
\begin{equation*}
\min_{i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}}\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_i}}e_i - z\right\|_2^2.
\end{equation*}

With a bit more work, it may be possible to tighten these bounds, or even reformulate your problem differently so as to find an exact solution. I hope this helps give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I was actually aware of the lifting procedure and I must have mentioned in my question that I am not interested in this relaxation because it scales to $\mathcal O(n^3)$ which is costly for my setting. I was hoping to find something of a smaller order. nevertheless, I sincerely appreciate your time and effort. Voting up!

Comment: Okay! I'll try to think of some alternate approaches in my free time.

Comment: That is very kind of you. Thank you.

Comment: Looks good! Did you use \underset to make the changes?

Comment: @brenderson Indeed, I did.