minimization involved $l_2$ norm
I am trying to find the minimum of the following problem
$$\frac{\theta}{2}\lVert\beta-x\rVert_2^2+\lambda\lVert x\rVert_2-\frac{1}{2\tau}\lVert x\rVert_2^2+\alpha^Tx$$
by taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and setting it to zero, I have
$$-\theta(\beta-x)+\lambda\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert_2}-\frac{1}{\tau}x+\alpha=0$$
I have trouble solving the problem because I have $\lVert x\rVert_2$ in my solution.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What is the connection to statistics? You’ve tagged the question as involving the statistics topics of [tag:regression] and [tag:machine-learning] but have not mentioned either in your question. Is this about, for instance, regularized regression?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681658/closed-form-solution-of-arg-min-x-left-x-y-right-22-lamb?noredirect=1&lq=1 I found what i need to.
